# Mysql update query is in general log but data is not changed

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, node-mysql

I'm using Node.js and MySQL in a batch process. The process makes a lot of queries concurrently and consists of many jobs. I've noticed that update statement works from time to time.

```
UPDATE `Configuration` SET `Value`='2015-06-08 11:35:00' WHERE `ID`=6
```

I've turned on general log and found the query there but data at the table hasn't been changed. The query runs at the end of a job approx once per 5 min. But other jobs continue making queries.

Example: 
jobA is making a lot of queries. At the same time jobC makes SELECT from Configuration table. Then jobC performs a bunch of queries not related to the Configuration table. Once jobC completes a bunch, it runs two queries against Configuration table: SELECT and then UPDATE.

Configuration table from the example isn't used in any other job or transaction.

I've found during testing that UPDATE Configuration table query is not working when jobA makes heavy load.

Can anyone suggest me what the problem is or where I should look further?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into isolation modes for MySQL.

I would need some more information about your problem (how often it doesn't update versus successfully updating and under what conditions) but if it is running too frequently the other transaction (if they are long?) may not have finished running and if it is not reading dirty data it may not execute an update. It all depends on the relative speed of the jobs and their isolation modes.

Comment: Example: jobA is making a lot of queries. At the same time jobC makes SELECT from `Configuration` table.
Then jobC performs a bunch of queries not related to the `Configuration` table. Once jobC completes a bunch, it runs two queries against `Configuration` table: SELECT and then UPDATE.
`Configuration` table from the example isn't used in any other job or transaction. 
I've found during testing that UPDATE `Configuration` table query is not working when jobA makes heavy load.

Comment: Is there any dependencies between jobA and jobC? What is the order of SQL statements that you need? How to separate work or wrap them together as transactions will become clear once you spell it out. Are you grouping anything together as a single transaction?